# Zend 2 Authentication for Facebook, Twitter and Google +

Tags: facebook, authentication, twitter, zend-framework2

I've been developing a web site where I need simple authentication. I've already have a form with simple fields (username, e-mail, password) but I also want to integrate facebook, twitter and google + authentication.
The problem is that I'm new in this kind of authentication and I've been searching at google for a nice tutorial (from beginning to end) but it has been worthless.
I've already had the client part working:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
                if (response.authResponse) {
                    this.location = '/facebook/token/' +  response.authResponse.accessToken;
                    testAPI();
                }
                else {
                    console.log(response.authResponse)
                    FB.login(function(response) {
                        if (response.authResponse) {
                            this.location = '/facebook/token/' +  response.authResponse.accessToken;
                        }}, {scope: 'email'});
            //FB.login();
        }
    });
```

Can anyone help me?

Thank you

Comment: Looking for the same thing. Have you had any success?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a module for that! Its [ScnSocialAuth](https://github.com/SocalNick/ScnSocialAuth). It is an amazing module and supports Google, Facebook, Twitter, Yahoo!, etc. I have used that and it is very easy to configure. Just configure the api keys and you are good to go!

Comment: Hi!! Thank you for your answer. I was wondering if you can give an example for facebook?

Comment: modules.zendframework.com uses github for authentication. This site also uses ScnSocialAuth. With ScnSocialAuth, you donot need worry about facebook, twitter or whatever. Just configure the api keys. You can see the source here https://github.com/zendframework/modules.zendframework.com

Comment: @Deepanshu Everything is there in the documentation. If that is not enough, create an issue!

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 2 has so called "service components" that provide simple API for accessing Twitter and other web services. Take a look at this page: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/index.html#zendservicereference